# Designing a database to contain databases ( database models )

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm working on an online database modeler in which users can:

- create new db schemas
- save schemas
- share schemas
- have revisions of schemas
- fork schemas
- comment on schemas

features include:

- JS draggable UI
- "live" ajax editing

I want to initially support MSSql, MySQL, Postgres, and SQLite. I want to create this database in Postgres. I have little Postgres experience, I have mostly dealt with MySQL.

Here's what I have come up so far:

### ***engines***

```
id           int( pk )
name         varchar(40)
```

sample data for engines:

```
(
    {"id":1,"name":"postgres"}, 
    {"id":2, "name":"mysql"}
)
```

### ***databases***

```
id           int ( pk )
name         varchar(100)
slug         varchar(40)
user_id      int
description  text
engine       int ( fk to engines.id )
fork_id      int ( keep track of forks )
parent_id    int ( this is for revisions )
comment_id   int ( fk to comments.id )
created      timestamptz(6)
modified     timestamptz(6)
```

sample data for databases:

```
(
    {
      "id":1,"name":"my first db",
      "slug":"my-first-db", 
      "user_id":3, 
      "description":"This is my first database.", 
      "engine":1,
      "created":"2009-09-01 22:22:10",
      "modified":"2009-09-01 22:22:10",
      "comments":3
     }
)
```

### ***tables***

```
id           int ( pk )
database_id  int ( fk to databases.id )
name         varchar(40)
x_position   int // this is the X position from the top left of the container
y_position   int // this is the Y position from the top left of the container
```

sample data for tables:

```
(
    {"id":1,"name":"customers", "database_id":1, "x_position":1, "y_position":2 }
)
```

### ***fields***

```
id             int ( pk )
table_id       int ( fk to tables.id )
name           varchar(40)
type           int ( fk to types.id )
default        varchar ( 100 )
size           int
autoincrement  tinyint(1)
null           tinyint(1)
```

sample data for fields:

```
(
    {"id":1,"name":"id", "type":2, "table_id":1, "autoincrement":1, "null":1 }
)
```

### ***foreign keys***

```
id                 int ( pk )
origin_field_id    int ( fk to fields.id )
remote_field_id    int ( fk to fields.id )
```

sample data for foreign keys:

```
(
    {"id":1,"origin_field_id":2, "remote_field_id":3 }
)
```

### ***types***

```
id                 int ( pk )
name               varchar(40)
```

sample data for foreign keys:

```
(
    {"id":1,"name":"BLOB" }
)
```

### ***types_engines ( mapping table )***

```
id                 int ( pk )
type_id            int
engine_id          int
```

sample data for foreign keys:

```
(
    {"id":1,"name":"BLOB" }
)
```

Since I'm a relatively novice SQLer, I would appreciate if anyone can point out critical design flaws I have made and point out things I have not thought about and have not forseen that may be critical. Here are things I need addressed.

- I have a `fork_id` and `parent_id` for my databases table. I would like to track whether databases were forked from other ones, *in addition* to keeping revisions of the forks. Do I need both of these in order to do that?
- Is the way I have modeled the engines, types and types_engines sufficient? Since different databases have different field types, I thought this would be an ideal way of handling that.
- Is my general design "good"? Or are there normalization improvements you can spot?

I realize that there are much more advanced features I'm not supporting such as views/triggers, but I think this will be useful in its simple nature.

Comment: Maybe a tinyint field for the fields table indicating primarykey.

Comment: Check mysqls metadata (information_schema) or oracles metadata and be inspired ;)

Comment: @Falcon - good idea, I was wondering where it was stored. Anyone happen to know how I can get the same metadata in Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the developers (who create databases) to be able to use all the features and facilities of SQL, that will not work.  You are going about it entirely the wrong way.  You have done a fair amount of work, designing tables, and so forth, which must be acknowledged; but all that is unnecessary, but that investment may hinder you from giving it up.  of course, if you implemented that structure, someone would have to (a) administer it and (b) maintain it.

As long as you have an ANSI SQL platform, those facilities for developers are already supplied, thoughtfully, completely, and to a published standard (as opposed to what you  or I may think is a good method of supplyin, controlling, and testing, shared objects).  please do not re-invent the wheel.

1. For the free and easy, unrestricted, learning area; which is most of your requirement:

   - In the server, Grant developers Create_Database permission.
   - They can administer their own *databases*, share them, etc, to their hearts desire.
     .
2. Before testing that any shared objects will work together, a slightly more constrained (than the free and easy) environment is required.  This is a single shared database, one, which you create and administer (or else, one, and only one, developer gets the DBA designation).

   - Create Users (one per developer)
   - Grant each user Create_Table (Rule, Proc, etc) permission
   - They can administer their own *objects*, share them, etc, to their hearts desire.
   - Each object owner is responsible for building objects, and sharing them, and testing them in their Owner area.  This is still not the single shared area that is relevant to formal testing before development of formal objects is commenced
   - That single shared area, for real testing, is DBO
   - As DBA, you only need to manage DBO objects
   - no one else is DBO
   - When a developer is ready to promote their private object to a formally shared object, they notify you
   - you simply copy the DDL of their private object, and execute it as DBO

That's all. All the tables, etc that are required for administration, is already implemented.  It is the SQL catalogue.

There are of course, many developer and DBA tools, which allow the tasks above to be done with a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

look up metadata management tools and/or ERWin or other database design tools